# p:autoComplete - getting data through custom AJAX call instead of bean

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

We're using PrimeFaces 5.3. Due to circumstances beyond my control, I need to get the data for an AutoComplete through an AJAX call instead of through a backing bean. I'm been able to make it work but have two problems:

1) In order to update the backing bean, I need to make the AJAX call synchronous

2) I'm not able to debounce the AJAX call

My technique so far (without debouncing) is:

On the AutoComplete, set a reference to my js function from the onkeydown event (I've also tried onkeypress):

```
<p:autoComplete id="myThing" completeMethod="#{myBean.completeMyThing}" onkeydown="myFunction(event)" />
```

In my script, define myFunction using a synchronous AJAX call, where the success handler calls a RemoteCommand:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  function myFunction(e) {       
    var value = e.srcElement.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "myURL",
        data: {
          query: value
        },
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
          myRCfunction( [{ name: 'param1', value: JSON.stringify(data) }, { name: 'query', value: value }] );
        }
      });
  }
  //]]>
```

Elsewhere on the page, define a RemoteCommand function which binds to the backing bean:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="myRCfunction" actionListener="#{myBean.handlerFn}" />
```

Finally, in the backing bean, I update the values used as suggestions by the AutoComplete:

```
public void handlerFn() {
    //get the request param values, and use them to update the list of things
    thingService.updateThings(things);
}
```

And finally, the completeMyThing function just gets the list of Things from the thingService:

```
public List<Thing> completeMyThing(String query) {
    List<Thing> allThings = thingService.getThings();
    return allThings;
}
```

This all works fine when you enter only one character; it doesn't work when you enter multiple characters, because the onkeydown event isn't debounced.

When I debounce the myFunction function, I start seeing console errors where the POJO converter is trying to run getAsObject instead of getAsString.

My first question is - isn't there an easier way to do this? As I said, I'm not able to do an HttpPost request from the backing bean for reasons beyond my control. That was my first attempt.

Second, I know that queryDelay debounces the AutoComplete's query... but that doesn't also debounce the onkeydown or onkeypress handlers; also, there doesn't seem to be an onstart handler? Is there an event that I can hook into that's already debounced?

This all seems awfully convoluted to me; but I'm a newbie to all things JSF.

**EDIT - after three days of struggling, it turns out there's already a service available to get this data. I've been able to discard this entire hack.**

Comment: Check out a REST client, like Jersey

Comment: I fail to see the real problem and why you can't do the call in the bean. Fire the person that prohibits this

Comment: @Kukeltje - would that I had the power to do so. This morning our senior dev informs me that we have an alternate way of getting the data so am about to look at that. Hopefully I can bag this entire hack.